# Finding the ISBN pattern by regexp in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have numerous text files that have book data in which I am trying to extract the *International Standard Book Number* (ISBN) from. Example snippets:

```
{" , "classifications": {}, "title": "La casa", "identifiers": {}, "isbn_13": ["978-84-940533-7-5"], "covers": [7281722], "created": {"type": "/type/datetime",
```

and

```
 "2014-07-28T06:07:52.898549"}, "number_of_pages": 408, "isbn_13": ["9789602354292"],
```

but how would I go about finding and extracting that ISBN information? Some of the ISBN numbers have dashes, and some do not. Is there a way to replace everything in the text file with a blank except for the snippets that match? I've done research on several similar questions, but having a hard time comprehending it all as I am very new to Notepad++.

Comment: See this link http://markantoniou.blogspot.com.es/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have your ISBN and some more text in a text file line by line you'd go through following steps:

**Make a copy of your text file first!**

- Open your text file in Notepad++.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Find what: `^.*?(((1[03])*[ ]*(: ){0,1})*(([0-9Xx][- ]*){13}|([0-9Xx][- ]*){10})).*`
- Replace with: \1
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

For RegEx please search Google or StackOverflow first. For further information have a look at [RegExLib.com](http://www.regexlib.com), the Internet's first Regular Expression Library.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I gave this a shot, and while it isolated some ISBN's, it did not isolate all, and appeared to completely stop after line 10,000 or so. I tried the ISBN example on the RegEx library, but am still having issues.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out. Thanks!! Much appreciated.